# How sort words into each record (user function)?

Tags: filemaker

I have some records in my database:

```
Record 1: I knock the door
Record 2: I do not believe that
Record 3: They bought shoes, trousers and shirts
Record 4: They stayed with him in silence
```

Result after applying the user function:

```
Record 1: door I knock the
Record 2: believe do I not that
Record 3: and bought shirts shoes They trousers
Record 4: him in silence stayed They with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be accomplished with this calculation,

Trim ( Substitute ( SortValues ( Substitute ( "I knock the door"; " "; ¶ ) ); ¶; " " ) )

Result will be "door I knock the"

Replace the text "I knock the door" with your field name.

Comment: Good answer, but worth mentioning that it will only work for FileMaker Pro 16 and above